# DHCP server not starting

Tags: 12.04, server, dhcp

I'm trying to set a DHCP server on 12.04. I installed:

`sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server`

My configuration files look like this:

*/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server*

```
INTERFACES="eth0"
```

*/etc/network/interfaces*

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

*/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf*

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
{
    range                       192.168.1.235 192.168.1.240;
    option subnet-mask          255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address    192.168.1.255;
    option routers              192.168.1.1;
    default-lease-time          100000;
    max-lease-time              100000;
}
```

When I run `sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart` I get:

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
isc-dhcp-server start/running, process 15384
```

After this if I run `sudo service isc-dhcp-server status` it shows that its stopped:

```
isc-dhcp-server stop/waiting
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the output of your /var/log/syslog,  after you attempt to start the dchp server

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

your server must have a static IP. that ip must not be in your dhcp IP range
Restart networking deamons and restart dhcp as well

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

 sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart
```